# Cannot connect to any database after upgrading OpenSSH

Tags: mysql, connection, openssh, database, wordpress

I upgraded OpenSSH with this command:
`sudo apt-get upgrade openssh-server`

I rebooted the server and after that, I cannot connect to any database (WordPress database, you'll database, phpmyadmin database)

For WordPress I get: Error establishing a database connection

For yourls I get: Incorrect DB config, or could not connect to DB

For phpmyadmin I get:
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory

I think that it's a `mysql` problem because it does not start and when I check mysql.service I find that's failed

What's the solution please!

This is the error log /var/log/mysql/error.log

[image: This is the error log /var/log/mysql/error.log]

[image: This is the error log /var/log/mysql/error.log]

systemctl status mysql.service
[image: systemctl status mysql.service]

journalctl -xe
[image: journalctl -xe]

[image]

[image]

Mysql status:
[image]

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with SSH. The solution is to work out why MySQL is not starting. You should post your logs/error outputs to determine why.

Comment: I added the error log in /var/log/mysql/error.log Thanks

Comment: added also results for  systemctl status mysql.service and journalctl -xe

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution was to go to:  etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
I found mysqld.cnf permission set to 644
I change it to 777 and the MySQL works again.
I don't know why running the upgrade with this command
sudo apt-get upgrade openssh-server
changed many permissions to files and directories.

I think that 777 is too open, can I make a less permission without stoping MySQL? what permission do you advise me to both mysqld.cnf and my.cnf in those directories?
etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
and
etc/mysql/my.cnf